# Kernel Restarting with Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, parallel-processing

I am encountering an issue when trying to parallelize a computation using Spark in Jupyter Notebook. The code works fine with a small dataset but fails with larger datasets, causing the kernel to die.

I wrote some code that runs on jupyter notebook.
We are talking about generation of a synthetic dataset and consecutive skyline calculation. I premise that with a not too large number of data (up to 5 million tuples with 4 dimensions) the code works correctly.
The goal is to use parallelization algorithms via spark. I have four virtual machines at my disposal, each of which has 30 cores and 8gb of RAM. I was able to create a spark cluster, with one machine acting as the master and then the others as workers.
This is the master's spark web page:
[Spark Master Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3owK.png)

This, on the other hand, is the spark web page of one of the workers:
[Spark Worker Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z0SX.png)

The spark-defaults.conf file has this content:

```
spark.driver.memory 6g
spark.executor.memory 6g
```

The spark session is started like this:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.\
        master("spark://<master-ip>")\
        .config("spark.files", files_string)\
        .getOrCreate()
print("spark session created")
```

And the lines of code where the kernel dies are as follows:

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data, numberOfSlices)

initialValues = rdd.mapPartitions(lambda x: skyline.find_skyline_sfs(x, weights)).collect()
```

To clarify it correctly computes the idd output of parallelize, and returns the error when the next line is executed. I tried to eliminate collect() because I thought it was too wasteful but I need the results, and without collect on the find_skyline_sfs() function is called. I also tried the other spark peer functions write to file but it always returns the same error. Which to be exact is as follows:
The kernel for skyline_code/skyline_test.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it? thanks